# Want to make a checkbox filter using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to make a checkbox filter with PDO but I don't know how. After trying for quite some time and searching the internet, I still had no luck.

What I'm trying is to show all projects I made (which are taken from a database) and displaying them in a `<div>` called gallery. On the left is a bar called helpbar with the checkboxes (also taken from a database).

the websoft table includes all my projects, the filter table includes all filter options (like websites and apps).

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="helpbar">
        <div class="helpbar-block">
        <?php $query=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `portfoliodb`.`filter`");
        $query->execute();
        while   ( $row = $query->fetch()) {
            $filter_id = $row['filter_id'];
            $filter_name = $row ['filter_name'];

            echo'<table class="helpbar-table">
                    <tr> <td><input type="checkbox" name ="websoft" checked class="filter-checkbox">'; echo htmlspecialchars($filter_name); echo'</td></tr>
                 </table>';

        }?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery">
        <?php   $query=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `portfoliodb`.`websoft`");
        $query->execute();

        while   ( $row = $query->fetch()){
            $websoft_id = $row['websoft_id'];
            $websoft_name = $row ['websoft_name'];
            $websoft_desc_en = $row ['websoft_desc_en'];
            $websoft_img = $row ['websoft_img'];
            $websoft_type = $row ['websoft_type'];
            echo'<a><div class="gallery-item">
                <p class="gallary-item-text">';
                 echo htmlspecialchars($websoft_name);
                echo'</p></div></a>';
```

`websoft_type` basically means the filter (so if it's a website then `websoft_type = website`).

I hope you can make sense of the rather nooby code and help me out of my problem. Thank you for your time and answers.

--Edit--

It's no problem if the filter system isn't controlled from the DB if that makes it easier.

Comment: try learning about ajax and jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically solved it by changing my database and adding an if/else statement.